# Load specific js for certain pages in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 for a project. Is there any way I can specify what js files I want to load for a certain view. Right now I am lumping all in one file.

When I use codeigniter, to load specific js files, i use a library to generate the script tags and echo them at the footer. something as below

```
$this->data['js'] = $this->js_lib->generate('jquery');
```

Then in my view

```
<?= $js ?>
```

Any idea how to do this in laravel?

Answer (score 29):

Main Layout

main.blade.php

```
@include('includes.header')

<body>
    <!-- main content -->
    <div id="main_wrapper">
        <div class="page_content">
             @yield('content')
        </div>      
    </div>

@include('includes.footer')

</body>
```

---

header.blade.php

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">

<!-- common styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap.css') }}">      
<!-- page specific styles -->
    @yield('pagespecificstyles')
</head>
```

---

footer.blade.php

```
<footer>
<!-- common scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- page specific scripts -->
@yield('pagespecificscripts')
```

mypage.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('pagespecificstyles')

    <!-- flot charts css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/lib/owl-carousel/flot.css') }}">

@stop

@section('content')
<div class="container">
        Hello welcome to my page.
</div>
@endsection

@section('pagespecificscripts')
    <!-- flot charts scripts-->
    <script src="{{ asset('/assets/lib/flot/jquery.flot.min.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 13):

**Stacks**

Blade allows you to push to named stacks which can be rendered somewhere else in another view or layout. This can be particularly useful for specifying any JavaScript libraries required by your child views:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

You may push to a stack as many times as needed. To render the complete stack contents, pass the name of the stack to the @stack directive:

```
    <!-- Component Contents -->
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks

Comment: this is vey fluent way and helped me lot thaks buddy

Comment: Why has this answer not been voted up more?  Thanks. The perfect fast solution.

Comment: Best practice is to put scripts right before the closing body tag: `@stack('scripts')</body>`

Answer (score 9):

I know asked a while ago but for the benefit of others who may stumble here! One option is also in your layout to define additional sections, e.g.

```
@yield('css') <!-- In the head -->

@yield('js') <!-- Before the </body> tag -->
```

Then in your views

```
@extends('some.layout')

@section('css')
    @include('js/dependencies/some/js/dependency/css.css')
@append

<!-- So in case these dependencies are used elsewhere you're not repeating your script or link tags over and over -->

@section('js')
    @include('js/dependencies/some/js/dependency/js.js') 
    @include('js/dependencies/some/js/dependency/js2.js')
@append

@section('content')

    Your actual content

@endsection
```

Comment: Does this work for laravel 4 or is it laravel 5 only?

Comment: This will work on 4 and 5, but now on 5 we have stack, which does essentially the same thing, but it's specific purpose is for this kind of thing

Comment: Also, can the people voting my answer down give me constructive feedback as to why it's been voted down?

Answer (score 1):

Just have a 'partials' view folder - and include whatever script you want in each view.

So in your view;

```
<body>
    // Your main content here
    // Other JS files you want in all views

    @include('partials.analytics.blade.php')

    @include('partials.googlemaps')

    @include('partials.some_other_js_file')

</body>
```

Then have /views/partials/analytics.blade.php

```
<script>
  // Your JS analytics script here
</script>
```

and just repeat for each 'script'

Answer (score 1):

> You may add the following code in your app.blade file

```
@stack('scripts')
```

> and then you can use the jquery on page

```
@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
 ///Js code
</script>
@endpush
```